# Odd horizontal line in SVG

Tags: svg, opera

I'm making a polygon clipper demo program and found a problem, that cannot solve.

All other browsers shows [the example svg](http://jsfiddle.net/bxrUm/) as expected, but newest Opera 12.11 (in Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.6) shows some odd horizontal line.

Opera 12.11 result:
[image: Opera svg result]

Other browser's (IE9, Firefox, Safari, Chrome) result:
[image: Other browser's result]

I expect this is a bug in Opera because all other browsers shows the right result, but not sure, because when I eg. remove some Z in path command, also Opera shows the right result.

What could be wrong in my SVG or is it a bug in Opera?

Problematic path:

```
<path style="fill:#80ff9C; fill-opacity:0.5; stroke:#003300; stroke-opacity:1.00; stroke-width:0.80;" id="p3" d="M167.12,227.93L164.78,225.58L164.78,201.75L163.53,203L142.92,203L140.9,200.97L138.87,203L118.45,203L116.11,200.65L116.11,200.43L114.14,201.09L113.87,201.16L106.39,202.53L106.15,202.56L96.48,203.17L96.22,203.17L88.33,202.67L88.05,202.63L81.88,201.36L81.55,201.26L76.74,199.37L76.36,199.18L72.51,196.63L72.16,196.34L69.06,193.09L68.8,192.73L66.34,188.65L66.17,188.3L64.3,183.01L64.21,182.69L62.96,175.77L62.94,175.53L62.45,166.59L62.44,166.32L62.83,161.46L56.41,160.67L56.12,160.6L52.27,159.53L52.27,187.6L49.92,189.95L26.52,189.95L24.18,187.6L24.18,83.41L26.52,81.07L49.92,81.07L52.26,83.4L52.26,83.68L52.45,83.58L52.75,83.46L58.61,81.53L58.96,81.45L64.69,80.67L65.08,80.65L72.44,81.09L72.72,81.13L79.06,82.42L79.39,82.52L83.26,84.05L83.69,84.29L87.35,86.93L87.68,87.22L91.13,91.09L91.33,91.38L94.37,96.28L94.54,96.62L96.5,101.85L96.59,102.16L96.73,102.82L97.48,100.58L97.61,100.27L100.23,95.33L100.44,95.02L103.76,90.87L104.02,90.6L107.95,87.24L108.26,87.02L113.01,84.32L113.34,84.16L118.9,82.22L119.21,82.14L125.69,80.98L125.93,80.96L131.95,80.65L132.32,80.65L140.3,81.11L140.56,81.14L147.02,82.4L147.33,82.49L152.58,84.42L152.92,84.58L157.36,87.23L157.67,87.46L161.42,90.82L161.69,91.13L164.68,95.19L164.88,95.54L167.12,100.34L167.24,100.65L168.03,103.46L168.03,54.67L170.37,52.33L193.56,52.33L195.91,54.67L195.91,81.07L217.13,81.07L219.12,82.36L235.15,118.59L249.15,82.45L251.21,81.06L267.29,81.15L269.65,84.63L267.35,90.56L268.9,88.56L269.17,88.27L272.65,85.24L273.05,84.97L276.65,83.1L277.08,82.93L282.96,81.43L283.26,81.38L290.26,80.67L290.56,80.66L295.53,80.9L295.87,80.96L301.02,82.12L301.34,82.22L305.26,83.84L305.26,83.4L307.6,81.06L331,81.06L333.35,83.41L333.32,106.07L335.16,100.58L335.29,100.27L337.92,95.33L338.12,95.03L341.43,90.88L341.71,90.6L345.65,87.24L345.95,87.03L350.69,84.32L351.02,84.17L356.58,82.22L356.89,82.14L363.36,80.98L363.61,80.96L369.63,80.65L370.01,80.65L377.98,81.11L378.24,81.14L384.71,82.4L385.02,82.49L390.27,84.42L390.6,84.57L395.04,87.22L395.37,87.45L399.12,90.83L399.38,91.13L402.37,95.19L402.57,95.54L404.81,100.34L404.93,100.65L405.38,102.26L405.38,83.41L407.72,81.07L431.34,81.07L433.68,83.4L433.68,83.92L438.94,82.01L439.27,81.92L445.06,80.88L445.37,80.85L452.26,80.69L452.57,80.71L458.4,81.45L458.76,81.53L463.42,83.03L463.82,83.22L467.58,85.44L467.99,85.75L471.27,89.06L471.55,89.41L473.86,93.1L474.07,93.55L475.38,97.53L475.47,97.96L475.81,101.25L475.82,101.45L475.82,158.65L473.47,161L455.03,161L452.69,158.66L452.58,103.42L452.18,102.16L451.48,101.27L450.13,100.42L447.35,99.61L443.1,99.28L439.59,100.03L437.44,101.06L435.97,102.39L433.88,105.3L433.69,105.76L433.69,133.06L435.2,133.06L437.55,135.41L437.42,204.06L437.38,204.48L436.39,209.01L436.24,209.46L434.39,213.27L434.11,213.69L431.39,216.92L431.05,217.24L427.42,219.9L427.06,220.11L422.33,222.23L422,222.34L416.02,223.84L415.74,223.89L408.17,224.68L407.94,224.69L398.86,224.52L398.63,224.51L390.95,223.53L390.68,223.47L382.84,221.31L382.48,221.17L379.33,219.61L378.17,217.99L376.45,204.99L380.33,202.19L387.08,205.47L392.85,207.48L398.67,208.52L401.88,208.75L406.92,208.37L409.73,207.59L411.2,206.7L411.81,205.95L412.16,204.84L412.18,202L406.35,203.16L406.04,203.21L399.45,203.51L399.12,203.49L392.54,202.71L392.22,202.64L386.95,201.09L386.52,200.91L383.24,199.05L382.81,198.73L379.7,195.66L379.42,195.32L376.61,190.96L376.43,190.64L375.24,187.75L375.24,200.65L372.89,203L356.55,203L354.21,200.66L354.13,159.59L351.66,158.84L351.33,158.71L346.46,156.26L346.13,156.06L342.02,152.9L341.73,152.62L341.2,152.01L339.97,153.37L339.06,154.95L338.95,200.66L336.61,203L315.82,203L314.06,201.23L312.29,203L291.67,203L289.33,200.65L289.33,187.37L287.34,191.69L287.16,192.02L284.34,196.01L284.05,196.34L280.91,199.18L280.46,199.49L276.95,201.25L276.58,201.38L271.17,202.84L270.84,202.9L264.39,203.53L264.05,203.54L257.14,203.02L256.83,202.97L252.4,201.93L252.4,225.58L250.05,227.93L229.43,227.93L227.09,225.58L227.09,187.22L225.03,191.69L224.85,192.01L222.04,196.01L221.73,196.34L218.59,199.17L218.15,199.48L214.66,201.24L214.28,201.38L208.87,202.84L208.54,202.9L202.08,203.53L201.74,203.54L194.84,203.02L194.54,202.98L190.09,201.94L190.09,225.58L187.74,227.93Z
M197.78,187.5L200.78,187.08L202.89,186.23L204.29,185.11L205.42,183.44L205.87,182.24L205.56,182.06L199.49,170.19L201.9,166.35L208.29,166.49L207.83,159.77L206.88,155.37L205.71,152.86L204.43,151.38L202.73,150.31L200.12,149.55L196.5,149.28L195.91,149.42L195.91,158.65L193.56,161L190.1,161L190.13,185.7L191.31,186.36L194.26,187.2Z
M260.09,187.5L263.09,187.08L265.2,186.23L266.6,185.11L267.74,183.43L268.52,181.3L266.75,180.35L265.65,178.75L263.75,164.25L267.66,161.46L270.35,162.79L270.15,159.77L269.19,155.37L268.59,154.07L266.01,150.91L265.05,150.31L262.43,149.55L258.81,149.28L255.92,149.95L253.38,151.25L252.39,152.03L252.44,185.7L253.62,186.36L256.57,187.2Z
M405.83,187.49L409.74,186.84L412.25,185.76L412.25,161L407.72,161L405.38,158.65L405.38,149.33L404.68,149.3L401.46,149.83L399.56,150.66L396.77,153.62L396.57,153.79L396.4,154.04L395.29,157.12L394.34,162.91L394.05,170.1L394.62,176.48L395.76,181.05L397.11,184.03L398.39,185.5L400.11,186.58L402.55,187.31Z
M98.91,186.95L104.73,186.33L110.5,184.76L114.04,183.1L115.91,181.35L116.11,181.45L116.11,159.49L113.97,158.84L113.64,158.71L108.76,156.26L108.45,156.06L104.34,152.9L104.05,152.62L101.14,149.24L98.46,149.07L95.15,149.49L92.97,150.33L91.58,151.43L90.57,152.94L89.18,156.73L88.31,161.67L88.16,168.46L88.8,175.96L90,181.31L91.09,183.87L92.25,185.3L93.69,186.24L95.82,186.86Z
M61.37,144.33L65.04,143.91L67.63,143L69.49,141.72L70.86,140.06L72.38,136.66L73.77,131.21L74.63,123.89L74.66,116.82L73.94,109.89L72.81,105.46L71.51,102.88L69.94,101.12L68.08,99.95L65.08,99.01L60.82,98.6L57.91,99.06L55,100.23L52.28,102.1L52.37,141.97L53.93,142.85L56.98,143.81Z
M373.19,143.31L373.75,143.23L375.49,142.45L376.68,141.36L377.59,139.78L378.8,135.24L379.65,127.98L379.81,118.04L379.15,109.78L377.96,104.02L377,101.64L375.9,100.29L374.44,99.36L372.16,98.74L369.06,98.65L366.18,99.21L364.22,100.16L362.96,101.34L361.94,103.15L360.64,107.73L359.76,114.54L359.55,120.81L360.41,133.12L360.51,133.62L361.39,133.78L361.8,133.9L365.83,135.57L366.28,135.83L369.42,138.21L369.77,138.56L372.52,141.97L372.78,142.4Z
M289.33,142.66L289.33,135.4L291.67,133.06L293.32,133.06L292.17,132.18L291.75,131.74L289.59,128.68L289.32,128.12L288.23,124.69L288.14,124.09L288.12,120.36L288.2,119.79L289.21,116.36L289.46,115.81L291.52,112.69L291.94,112.24L294.62,110.06L295.19,109.73L298.41,108.54L298.91,108.42L301.8,108.14L302,108.13L302.24,108.13L302.49,108.14L305.26,108.51L305.26,102.2L301.81,100.1L298.17,98.83L296.56,98.6L292.77,99.04L289.99,100L288.01,101.33L286.35,103.26L284.95,106.06L283.76,110.68L282.92,118.05L282.88,124.86L283.64,131.68L284.96,136.7L286.48,139.95L287.9,141.66Z
M252.13,135.13L252.21,135.09L252.5,134.97L257.7,133.34L258.08,133.26L259.63,133.09L259.35,131.43L259.32,131.21L258.81,121.7L258.81,121.48L259.34,112.27L259.37,112.05L259.65,110.44L250.64,133.68Z
M212.81,134.34L195.91,96.07L195.91,133.24L200.92,132.68L201.29,132.68L208.07,133.23L208.38,133.28Z
M141.22,134.33L141.74,129.97L141.22,129.23Z
M141.22,115.01L141.81,114.13L141.47,109.79L140.27,104.02L139.32,101.64L138.22,100.29L136.75,99.36L134.47,98.74L131.37,98.65L128.49,99.21L126.53,100.16L125.25,101.36L124.25,103.14L122.97,107.7L122.89,108.31L138.87,108.31L141.22,110.65Z" fill-rule="nonzero">
</path>
```

EDIT: When I change "stroke-width" from "0.80" to "0.81" Opera shows the right result, but "0.85" shows the odd horizontal line in other place. Really weird!

Comment: I was seeing a similar SVG rendering bug in recent Safari releases that I was able to overcome by simply removing a style that I had applied: shape-rendering: crispEdges;